# Laravel - How to get where the count of a relationship is greater than value of a column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

My model setup is as follows:

A project has a project gallery

```
public function project_gallery(){
    return $this->hasOne(ProjectGallery::class);
}
```

A project gallery can have many gallery images

```
public function images(){
    return $this->hasMany(GalleryImage::class);
}
```

A project has a project type, which has a field "num_images_required"

```
public function project_type(){
    return $this->belongsTo(ProjectType::class);
}
```

I need to get all projects where the number of gallery images is greater than or equal to the "num_images_required" field on the associated project type. I have a scope setup for this and it works with a static number, but I can't seem to pull the "num_images_required" field into the logic. Do I need some kind of sub-query to achieve this?

```
public function scopeimagesComplete($query){
    return $query->whereHas('project_gallery.images', null, '>=', 'project_type.num_images_required');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a solution without joins, but we can combine a *join* with *whereHas* to reduce the code a bit:

```php
public function scopeImagesComplete($query) {

    $tbName = $this->getTable();
    $projectTypeTbName = (new ProjectType())->getTable();

    return $query->join($projectTypeTbName, "$projectTypeTbName.id", '=', "$tbName.project_type_id")
                 ->whereHas('project_gallery.images', null, '>=', DB::raw("$projectTypeTbName.num_images_required"));
}
```

Here I used two variables to be able to abstract the table names, but if you prefer you can hardcode them and remove the variables.